# Creating a stack based binary expression calculator using visitor and builder pattern

Tags: c++, binary-tree, builder, visitor-pattern

So, I am creating a stack based binary expression calculator using visitor and builder pattern where the binary expression is stored in a binary tree.  I am using a stack based visitor pattern.  I can parse a string to construct the binary tree just fine, however I can't figure out how to finally calculate the tree after creating it using a visitor pattern.

For example, my tree would look like this for the expression (((5+4)*50)-(10/20):

```
     -
  *     /
 + 50 10 20
5 4
```

For example

```
root->getValue();  //this returns "-"
root->getRC()->getValue();  //this returns "/"
root->getRC()->getRC()->getValue();  //this returns "20"
```

The only relevant code is:

```
//Node Class
//gets the value, for example 5,4,+,-,etc..
string getValue() {
    return value;
}
void Accept(Visitor* v) {
    v->VisitNode(this);
}
//gets left child node
Node* getLC() const {
    return left;
}
//gets right child node
Node* getRC() const {
    return right;
}
```

And I wrote the framework for this particular visitor.  I just need help with the VisitNode class.

```
class CalVis: public Visitor{
public:
stack<unsigned int> s;
public:
CalVis(){};
//need help with this
virtual void VisitNode(Node* n){
}
//When I call this in main, it will return the value of my binary tree
double getResult() {
    unsigned int result =s.top();
    m_stack.pop();
    return result;
}
};
```

My main would look something like this

```
CalVis cv;
//root in my example would be a node pointing to the - value
root->Accept(&cv);
//Would be the numerical value of (((5+4)*50)-(10/20) solved
cout<<endl<<"The result: "<<sbsv.getResult()<<endl;
```

Comment: Accept needs to be virtual here in order for this to work properly (and defined in every class). There should be multiple VisitNode functions, each taking the exact type of the node. For instance, virtual void VisitNode(AddNode* n){}; virtual void VisitNode(SubtractionNode* n){}; I would recommend using boost::variant or std::variant instead.

Comment: I only have 1 node class.  There aren't different types of nodes.  I edited to give an example, but getValue() would return +,-,10,20, etc